# Instagram Api Registration Questions

Tags: android, api, instagram

So I am in the process of creating an android application that involves the user logging into Instagram and then etc. I just have few questions that haven't been answered when registering an application. Since my app is on an android device, what URL's should I use for my website, and OAuth redirect_url? I understand what these urls do, website being where the calls are going to be coming from and the redirect_url is the url in which the user will be sent back to once a user either grants or denies access. But I am not making a webApp so please help as I can not find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a webview in android app to open instagram login page then you can just use any dumy URL like `http://localhost/redirect` and then in your android java code, intercept the "on start load" event for webview, check for "localhost/redirect" in url and grab the `code` in URL param, close webview and do a http POST to get `access_token` (assuming you are doing a server explicit oauth)